# Changing foreach-loop into a method including XmlNode

Tags: c#, methods, foreach

I have a foreach loop using an XmlNodeList called "flights". So the foreach itself looks like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode flight in flights)
        {
         *code*
        }
```

and in this foreach-loop I am getting several strings using this (here I am setting a Label):

```
callsign.Text = flight.Attributes.GetNamedItem("callsign").Value;
```

But now, I dont want a foreach anymore, I need to use the same code as a method. But when i rewrite the foreach line mentioned above with

`public void CreateFlight()`

it says everywhere where I am using the `flight.Attributes.GetNamedItem` etc. "The name "flight" does not exist in the current context".

Comment: So you haven't declared the variable "flight" in your scope.  Without the rest of the code, I can't tell you where you're not putting it.

Comment: Well you need an `XmlNode` to get the attributes from... it's not at *all* clear where you're expecting to get that from.

Comment: You didn't just *rewrite* but *deleteed* previous statements, so you missed the variable. That is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either pass a `flight` object into your method or create a new one inside the method. Given the name I suspect the latter:

```
public void CreateFlight()
{
    XmlNode flight = new XmlNode();

    // The rest of your code

    // Do something with the flight object?
}
```

But this will just create an empty object which you would need to populate from somewhere. However, your usage and comments imply that you need something like this:

```
public string CreateFlight(XmlNode flight)
{
    return flight.Attributes.GetNamedItem("callsign").Value;
}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode flight in flights)
{
    string callSign = CreateFlight(flight);
}
```

Comment: This looks good, however this seems to create an empty XmlNode. I need an XmlNode including some of the data from XmlNodeList mentioned in first line. There is an XmlNodeList "flights" with an xml path set to the "flight" element in it. The flight looks like this:
<flight callsign="something"; destination="something" etc. />
and in this method I am getting all of these informations.

Comment: @MarekBuchtela You'll need to pass that data into your method and read the relevant information out.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
public string CreateFlight(XmlNode flight)
{
    return flight.Attributes.GetNamedItem("callsign").Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
callsign.Text = CreateFlight(flight);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `CreateFlight` method to accept an `XmlNode` argument called `flight`.  When you call `CreateFlight`, pass in the node you are going to extract data from.